# React - toggle color for adjacent elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm creating a gameBoard, and having trouble toggling background colors for button divs. The toggle works for individual clicks on the "buttons" (styled divs), but when I click adjacent buttons it requires two clicks to get the next button to change its background color. How can I get adjacent buttons to toggle on first click? I've read some  related posts like ([Changing style of a button on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978408/changing-style-of-a-button-on-click)) but still struggling to get this working -

Related code below,
full code: https://jsfiddle.net/lydiademi/kt2qgfpr/

TY!

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    color: '#FFF',
    color_white: true,
    currentWord: '',
    board1: [],
    row1: ["aaafrs","aaeeee","aafirs","adennn","aeeeem"],
  }

  this.clicked = this.clicked.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount() {
  let letter1 = '';

  this.state.row1.forEach(die => {
    letter1 = die[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)].toUpperCase();
    if (letter1 === 'Q') {
      this.state.board1.push("Qu")
    } else {
      this.state.board1.push(letter1);
    }
  })
}

clicked(event) {
  //change background color
  let newColor= this.state.color === "#FFF" ? "#ACCEEC" : "#FFF";
  this.setState({ color: newColor });
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
}

render () {
  return ( 
   <div id="board">
      <div className="row">
        {

          this.state.board1.map((letter, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="btn" onClick={(e) => {this.clicked(e)}}> 
              {letter}
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
  ) 
}
```

Comment: Your board moves as it is clicked :o

Comment: It's more of a javascript issue, so I have edited the tags. I guess the issue is in this code `var newColor= this.state.color === "#FFF" ? "#ACCEEC" : "#FFF";
    this.setState({ color: newColor });
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = newColor;`

Comment: The issue is in the state and update. Notice, that all buttons do not "switch" as expected after initial state. As described, "...it requires two clicks."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is :

You are maintaining one variable for all the elements bg toggle,
So the code is working as it should,

There is no need for maintaining state for that.

---

What you can do is :

Set extra attribute `data-color` like this

```
<div className="btn" data-color='#FFF' onClick={(e) => {this.clicked(e)}}>
```

And change bg color and `attr` based upon `data-color` , onClick like this

```
clicked(event) {

    // get current color of element
    let currentColor = event.target.attributes['data-color'].value;

    // apply condition based upon currentColor
    let newColor = currentColor === "#FFF" ? "#ACCEEC" : "#FFF";

    // set the bg color 
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = newColor;

    // change the data-color value to currentColor
    event.target.setAttribute('data-color' , newColor);

    // add letter to state.currentWord
    let letter = event.target.innerText;
    this.setState({ currentWord: this.state.currentWord + letter })
}
```

Here is the link to working fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/vivekdoshi2/kt2qgfpr/2/

Comment: ^thank you for clear explanation, would you know how to select elements within the render so that I could clear board (ie data-color: "#FFF" for all divs with data-color attr) upon clicking submit (in submitWord method) I wanted to use .setAttribute property, I tried using something like  document.body.querySelector(''div .btn") thank you

Comment: @Lyddem, will you please accept and upvote the answer , as it sovles your current issue ?  for setting all to white again you can use querySelector on class name and loop thrugh each element and set data-color to white,