# Changing style of specific component returned from map function onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to change the style of individual TouchableOpacity components that have been returned from a map function.

Here is the component:

```
Example = ({ props }) => {  
    return (
        <View>
            {props.listExample.map(({ id }) => {
                return (
                    <React.Fragment key={id}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            style={styles.button}
                            onPress={() => console.log(id)}>
                            <Image source={require('example.jpg')} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </React.Fragment>
                );
            })}
        </View>
    );
};
```

Let TouchableOpacity = TO.

The map function returns about 30 TOs with unique IDs. When I click the TOs, I can see their unique ID in the console log. **I want to know how I can modify the style of an individual TO.**

Here is my render function which uses the functional component Example.

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.body}>
            <ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.column}>
                    <this.Example props={{ listExample: this.getList() }} />
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

**What I have tried:**

referencing [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978408/changing-style-of-a-button-on-click), I tried to create a function which changed the style of the TO when it is clicked. But the result of this changed all the TOs in the UI since of the way it is mapped.
I tried something like the following.

```
Example = ({ props }) => {  
    return (
        <View>
            {props.listExample.map(({ id }) => {
                let buttonStyle = this.state.pressed ? styles.button : styles.buttonClicked
                return (
                    <React.Fragment key={id}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            style={buttonStyle}
                            onPress={() => console.log(id)}>
                            <Image source={require('example.jpg')} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </React.Fragment>
                );
            })}
        </View>
    );
};
```

But as previously stated, this changed all of the Touchable Opacitys. Is there a way to only change one?

Thanks

**Edit - to show entire class**

```
class Page extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    MyButton = ({ onButtonPressed = () => {} }) => {
        const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(false);
        const onPressed = () => {
          setIsPressed(!isPressed);
          onButtonPressed();
       }
       return (<TouchableOpacity style={isPressed ? styles.pressedButton: styles.button}
                   onPress={onPressed}>
                   <Image source={require('example.jpg')} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
       );
    }

    Example = ({ props }) => {
        return (
            <View>
                {props.listExample.map(({ id }) => {
                    return (
                        <MyButton key={id}/>
                    );
                })}
            </View>
        );
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.body}>
                <ScrollView>
                    <View style={styles.column}>
                        <this.Example props={{ listExample: this.getList()}} />
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: You can assign an id if you want to simply style it in the css `id={id}`, or you can access the target of the click in the onClick function via the implicitly passed `event`, or you can update state onClick and conditionally style the relevant element on rerender.

Comment: If I create the TouchableOpacity like this: ``<TouchableOpacity id={id} ../>`` then how would I modify the style for just that TouchableOpacity? I see that it would have a unique ID I am just not sure how to access that in styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to separate the component inside map to a separate component and then handle style changes on press there

```
const MyButton = ({ onButtonPressed = () => {} }) => {
    const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(false);
    const onPressed = () => {
      setIsPressed(!isPressed);
      onButtonPressed();
   }
   return (<TouchableOpacity style={isPressed ? styles.pressedButton: styles.button}
               onPress={onPressed}>
               <Image source={require('example.jpg')} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
   )
}
```

so you can use in the map like this

```
Example = ({ props }) => {  
    return (
        <View>
            {props.listExample.map(({ id }) => {
                return (
                    <MyButton key={id} />
                );
            })}
        </View>
    );
};
```

Comment: So I would embed this component (MyButton) inside the map where I currently have the other TouchableOpacity? This seems like a good solution and I understand how it can solve my problem, but I cannot seem to figure out how to embed it into the map function. Would it be something like ``<React.Fragment key={id}> <MyButton />`` ?

Comment: Thanks for the update and yes this is what I tried. But I have an issue. If I define it as you have said ``const MyButton``, it shows unexpected token. I think this is because I cannot define something like this inside a JavaScript class. However, if I remove the ``const``, it cannot find variable ``MyButton``. I have also tried ``<this.MyButton key={id} /> `` and it said it was undefined. My apologies if this is trivial, I am quite new to RN and JS

Comment: Can you show me your complete code that you have tried so far?

Comment: All of my code is inside a class like: ``class Ex extends component { ... }``. So how am I to define this const MyButton? I probably should have stated this more clearly in the original post.

Comment: define the MyButton completely outside of Example, they are equally same level

Comment: I have updated the original post to show my code. I omitted some parts like imports and some helper functions which should not be a factor here. You can see I just have ``MyButton = ...`` not ``const MyButton``. It is defined outside of ``Example``.

Comment: better to move out Example and MyButton the same level as PAge and use Example without this.

Comment: I moved MyButton outside of the class Page and imported useState and it is now working. Thanks for following up with me.